# Why getting “Parameter is not valid” exception when creating an Image object from Memory stream of an image which size is greater that 100MB in C#?

Tags: c#

I have an application that showing the pictures uploading from the system. For that I have to add watermark string into the images while uploading. When adding watermark to large size images, I receive “Parameter is not valid” when create image object from a memory stream.
What is the reason for this? Is there any other way to add watermark for large images.

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(sourceFile.FullName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                using (Stream output = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (Image myImage = Image.FromStream(fs, false, false))
                    {
                        Font font = new Font(fontType, fontSize.Equals(0) ? 10 : fontSize, (FontStyle)fontStyle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
                        Color color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml(string.IsNullOrEmpty(fontColor) ? "#000000" : fontColor);
                        Point pt = new Point(10, 5);
                        SolidBrush brush = new SolidBrush(color);

                        using (Bitmap img = new Bitmap(new Bitmap(myImage)))
                        {
                            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(img))
                            {
                                graphics.DrawString(waterMarkText, font, brush, pt);
                                img.Save(output, GetImageFormatToDownload(sourceFile.Extension.ToUpper().Substring(1, sourceFile.Extension.Length - 1)));
                                using (Image imgFinal = Image.FromStream(output))
                                {
                                    using (var bmp = new Bitmap(img.Width, img.Height, img.PixelFormat))
                                    {
                                        using (var finalGraphics = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
                                        {
                                            finalGraphics.DrawImage(imgFinal, 0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
                                            bmp.Save(Path.Combine(storePath, storeName), GetImageFormatToDownload(sourceFile.Extension.ToUpper().Substring(1, sourceFile.Extension.Length - 1)));
                                            sourceFile = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(storePath, storeName));
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Thanks.

Comment: On what line is the exception thrown? What is the type of the exception? What does the stack look like?

Comment: Are you talking about 100MB of bitmap? Or 100MB of some compressed file? Why are you creating 3 `Bitmap` objects?

Comment: It is returning unexpected exception from below line whe I try to uload an image greater that 200MB.
          
            using (Bitmap img = new Bitmap(new Bitmap(myImage)))

Is there any other way to add water mark to large image?